# Arduino Skill Stop Push button error

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, button

I made a skill stop game from Arduino Uno and a pushbutton.Here is the code:

```
byte led_one=2;
byte led_two=3;
byte winner_led=4;
byte led_four=5;
byte led_five=6;
byte pushbutton=12;
byte score=0;
int pushbutton_value=digitalRead(pushbutton);

void setup() 
{
// put your setup code here, to run once:
   pinMode(led_one,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(led_two,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(winner_led,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(pushbutton,INPUT_PULLUP);
   pinMode(led_four,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(led_five,OUTPUT);
   Serial.begin(9600);
  }

void loop() 
{
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  for (int x=1;x<=6;x++)
  {
    digitalWrite(x,HIGH);
    delay(250);
    digitalWrite(x,LOW);
    delay(250);
    if(pushbutton_value==HIGH && x==winner_led)
    {
       score+=500;
    }
    else if(pushbutton_value==HIGH && x==led_one)
    {
       score+=100;
    }
  }
 Serial.println(score);
}
```

My Problem is that Whenever I push the button The Serial Monitor is printing out the wrong score
[image: serial print output]

Comment: It'll even notice that push button is pressed? I wonder how - the only reading is in `pushbutton_value` initialization. Also if you have `INPUT_PULLUP`, you should be checking for `LOW` as button should be switching ground.

Comment: LOW not working too

Comment: Well, more specifically: Where do you read the current state of the push button?

Comment: To the pushbutton_value variable

Comment: And when this digitalRead happens?

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: This happens once after the reset: `int pushbutton_value=digitalRead(pushbutton);`. Never ever again (except if you reset the MCU).

Comment: What should the score be? How do you want the scoring work?

Comment: The initialization of `int pushbutton_value` should be done after the IO has been stetted (in the `void setup()` after `pinMode(pushbutton,INPUT_PULLUP);`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why you initialized `score` as byte! Change it to `int`. As you can see when you `Serial Print` your `score` value doesn't cross 256 because the largest value a `byte` can have is 256 but you are summing `score` to 500

Comment: Hmm after I did this It still isnt working

Comment: digitalread your `pushbutton_value` in the loop, and whats was the output before..its still not crossing 256?

Comment: it is 0 now. What should I dp?

Comment: Could you please spoon feed me the code

Comment: How to predict the score without counting the number of `pushbutton_value==HIGH` recorded for the `x==winner_led` and `x==led_one` events ? Add 2 integers counters to follow those events.